# Play High-Resolution mp4 Videos on Galaxy Y

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-y

When I try to play high resolution videos on my phone I get this error message:

> Sorry, this video cannot be played

Is there a way to make these videos play, like an app that can handle these videos or is it a limitation of my device?

Comment: mp4 is not a supported format by default in android, your question shows very little research into the matter because a simple google query gave an answer.

Comment: @svarog Of course it does, http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html  But it doesn't matter because he's using touchwiz. Also, note that some questions here that could be answered by Google are now among the first results.

Comment: Check [here](http://galaxypockets5300.blogspot.in/2013/02/playing-hd-videos-in-your-samsung.html). I know it's for only for the Galaxy Pocket, but will work with the Galaxy Y, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry but your device cannot play high-res videos. Your device should be able to handle videos up to 640*360, this is the resolution of HQ YouTube.

Note that there's absolutely no point in watching HD videos on your phone. It has a screen resolution of 240 x 320. Anything above this will be scaled down to fit the screen.

Comment: In General, HD videos need to be decoded by a specialized companion chip (h264 decoder) because the CPU is not powerful enough. For price reasons, only a subset of h264's Features may be supported leaving you without HD support

Answer (score 1):

I can play all videos like 780p HD on Galaxy Y. Download [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad&hl=en) from Google Play.

Comment: If you can, please provide link to the app.

Answer (score -2):

Yes: *Galaxy Y* can play `.mp4` videos. I'll tell you how to do that:

The first thing you should do is download [Mx Player](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) from Playstore, install it and open the app. Enjoy your `.mp4` videos!

Comment: Please fix some typos and check your spelling. Other than that the answer is quite right.

Comment: And please avoid txtspeak. Keep in mind that many users here are not native English speakers, already having a hard time without that.

Comment: The answer, unfortunately, is not better than [the existing answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/39839/44325) and instead a dupe. Please avoid adding an answer if there's already a same answer.