# Able to play only few mp4 files in Samsung Galaxy Y?

Tags: video, samsung-galaxy-y

Why is it that I am able to play only a few .mp4 files in my New Samsung Galaxy Y Mobile but not he rest. What should I do to make even the other .mp4 files to play?

What should I do to make .mkv, .avi and other video formats to play?

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10316/what-is-the-recommended-video-format-codec-and-container-to-play-on-android-devi?rq=1 and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11498/video-player-to-play-all-files?rq=1

Comment: This seems like two very distinct questions - please consider separating them. You also may want to look at this previous question: [Play High-Resolution mp4 Videos on Galaxy Y](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24645)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deriving from the [link](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24645/13391) given in Comments:

Answer by [Richard](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/24649/13391)

> You are not able to play the high resolution videos in your mobile.
>   Your device should be able to handle videos up to 640*360, this is the
>   resolution of HQ YouTube.
>
> Note that there's absolutely no point in watching HD videos on your
>   phone. It has a screen resolution of 240 x 320. Anything above this
>   will be scaled down to fit the screen.

Comment by [ce4](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24645/play-high-resolution-mp4-videos-on-galaxy-y#comment29381_24649)

> In General, HD videos need to be decoded by a specialized companion
>   chip (h264 decoder) because the CPU is not powerful enough. For price
>   reasons, only a subset of h264's Features may be supported leaving you
>   without HD support

Comment: From the footer:  *"user contributions licensed under cc-wiki with attribution required"*

Answer (score 2):

Try [MX Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad) from Google Play.
It can play almost all the video formats in my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos. [Review](http://www.brorsoft.com/nexus-7/play-hd-videos-on-nexus7-with-best-video-player.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just install MX Player on your Android phone. Then, you can play any video format on your Samsung Galaxy Y Duos.